# Hovering over file does not show view count for all files, however in same site other files it does shows in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, administration, document

When we hovering over files its does not show view count, this issue is with only few files in that site however in same site other files it does shows View count and viewers name both.

We checked View feature is activated and still facing issue. Attached screenshot shows what I am experiencing, no view count displaying for most the files (file types- Word, excel, image))

[image]

Comment: Were the views for image files shown in the past?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in our SharePoint online document library and observed the same behavior.

I can see the views for office files like word, excel, ppt, etc. as well as mp4 files.

Word file:

[image]

MP4 file:

[image]

But I am unable to see the views and viewers for image file types (png, jpg, jpeg, etc.):

[image]

Maybe something changed at Microsoft end recently or they do not support showing views for image files. I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior: [Get support for Microsoft 365 - Online Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Comment: Thanks for heads up Ganesh!

Comment: In our case its not just with image file types, but with some of the other file types like word, excel too. Added image is just one of the example.

Comment: Check on library in another site once. If you still face the same issue, try raising support ticket with Microsoft directly and see if any issue with your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't reproduce your situation, we need to narrow down the problem and try some things.

1.You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.

2.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.

3.Are other users with permissions facing the same problem? View through another computer or account.

4.Whether all SharePoint pages have the same problem? You could create a new SharePoint page to check.

5.Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections.